# wpf comboBox coloring issue

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

Due to requirements, I need to have a comboBox that works as follows:

It uses:
 - one set of colors for fore/background when in view mode
 - A second set of colors for fore/background when in edit mode
 - Another set for selected mode (when the cursor is in the comboBox)
 - Another set for disabled mode

The user will never be able to edit the contents, just click on the down arrow and select from the list.

I have the comboBox working except for the colors.  Unlike other controls, simply trying to do the following (the triggers for edit mode) just doesn't work:

```
<MultiTrigger>
<MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Condition Property="IsFocused"
         Value="false" />
    <Condition Property="wpfMisc:myCtrl.viewMode"
         Value="false" />
    <Condition Property="IsEnabled"
         Value="true" />
</MultiTrigger.Conditions>
<Setter Property="BorderBrush"
    Value="{DynamicResource controls-editableBorderBrush}" />
<Setter Property="Background"
    Value="{DynamicResource controls-editableBackgroundBrush}" />
<Setter Property="Foreground"
    Value="{DynamicResource controls-editableForegroundBrush}" />
</MultiTrigger>
```

What do I need to set in my style so that I can change the fore/back color of the displayed SelectedItem - i.e. make the above work?

And I am curious if anyone can tell me why a control like this doesn't use a similar interface as other data entry controls (isn't that the whole idea of polymorphism?) This isn't a big deal, just curious, that's all.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to put #eeeeee (or whatever) in the values? Just to see if the dynamic resources work well

Comment: Dude... look up 'polymorphism'... that has absolutely nothing to do with what you said... and as a developer, you *really* should know what it is.

Comment: Yes, I tried using standard colors (red, blue, etc.) didn't help.

Comment: Sheridan - please read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science) - but here is the opening statement: "the provision of a single interface to entities of different types." I believe that's what I was asking about...

Comment: Dude, if that is what you think Polymorphism means, you've got problems. It relates to the ability to have multiple methods with the same name, but different input parameters, and the common interface between extended and base classes. Wikipedia is *not* a good place to learn programming from. However, don't get upset, I'm trying to help.

Comment: Please take a look at the [Polymorphism (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx) page on MSDN for a proper definition of Polymorphism, if you're interested.

Comment: Sheridan - This could be a fun discussion, but this isn't the place for it.  But I wish that they would at least attempt to maintain a common interface so I don't have to use a different approach to do the same thing with different controls - or at least understand the benefit of having so many different interfaces for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You don't achieve what you're after in the way that you are currently trying to achieve it. There is no need to use a `MultiTrigger`, just a number of sequential `Trigger` objects:

```
<ComboBox Width="150" Height="24">
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="ComboBox.Background" Value="Green" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ComboBox.IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ComboBox.Background" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="ComboBox.IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="ComboBox.Background" Value="Blue" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

Now, I've shown you the `IsEnabled` `Trigger` here to demonstrate that you *could* add multiple `Trigger` objects like this. However, you can't actually use this `Trigger` for `IsEnabled`, because there is a `Trigger` defined inside the default `ComboBox` that already has a `Trigger` set on that property (to make it look disabled). If you absolutely *have* to add a `Trigger` for `IsEnabled`, then you will have to implement your own `ControlTemplate` for the `ComboBox` to override that default behaviour. If this is the case, please take a look at the [ControlTemplate Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate.aspx) page on MSDN or ask a new question for help with this.

To address your other requirement of your 'view mode' is a bit more tricky. The code that you provided lookslike you are trying to retrieve the value directly from a class, rather than an instance of that class. In WPF, we normally add `public` properties into a view model or code behind file that we can bind to.

So I would imagine that you could have a `bool` property named `IsViewMode` and then you would add another `Trigger` like this:

```
                <Trigger Property="IsViewMode" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ComboBox.Background" Value="Orange" />
                </Trigger>
```

However, if your original syntax was correct, then your `Trigger` would look like this:

```
                <Trigger Property="wpfMisc:myCtrl.viewMode" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ComboBox.Background" Value="Orange" />
                </Trigger>
```

Comment: What if he composed the cb inside a Border and triggered that control?

Comment: Then only the `Border` would change colour, but most of it would be hidden by the `ComboBox`, so at best, we'd only see the stroke/line around the edge change colour.

Comment: Actually, the last example is what I am using and works great for other controls.  ViewMode has always been in the view model and the attached property is bound to it. I just included it so that people could see how I knew I was in view mode (view only vs. disabled - 2 different things.)

Comment: I agree about the multi trigger - I am using this approach until I have things works as it makes it very clear the conditions to which the colors apply.  Once it is all working, I plan to remove the redundant settings.